# Is it possible to unit-test this javascript structure?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

Given the following JavaScript structure:

```
addClickEvent: function() {
    element.addEventListener('click', function() {
        self.a();
        self.b();
    });
},
```

Is it possible to assert that `a()` and `b()` have been called without refactoring out the anonymous function or editing it's contents?

Comment: Is `self` defined somewhere else or is this the `window.self` that is in most browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the self in your code is the `window.self` property.

You could do something like this:

```
function element_onclick_callsAandB() {
    // Arrange
    var aCalled = false;
    var bCalled = false;
    var element = ...;

    var origA = self.a;
    var origB = self.b;

    self.a = function() {
        aCalled = true;
        origA();
    };
    self.b = function() {
        bCalled = true;
        origB();
    };

    try {
        // Act
        element.click();

        // Assert
        assertTrue(aCalled);
        assertTrue(bCalled);
    }
    finally {
        self.a = origA;
        self.b = origB;
    }
}
```

Comment: `self` is `this` at the same level as `addClickEvent()`

Comment: You need to somehow get a reference to self in order to be able to spy on it.  Can you get that in your test?

Comment: In the test I have instantiation of the object, so `object.addClickEvent()` works, however, I can't see a or b - I'm trying to make the case for refactoring out the anonymous function into it's own, named function, such as `respondToClick()`.